# Substitution function to clean up string

Tags: perl, substitution

I could split

```
$string = "AA_name"
```

into a @tmp array and grab $tmp[1] to obtain only the name and discard AA_. 
However, how would you do this with a s///? 
I don't know the regular expression to substitute everything preceding, and including, the underscore with nothing to leave me just the name. 
Something like

```
$n = $string =~ s/^_//;
```

But i'm fairly noob with regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$string =~ s/^[^_]+_//;
```

This means replace any leading characters that are not underscores, plus an underscore, with nothing; which means that subsequent underscores are left in there, ie.

```
AA_My_Name ==> My_Name
```

If you want to removed up to the last '_' then use:

```
$string =~ s/^.+_//;
```

Other separators can be used. If you want to use '.' then remember to escape it with a '\'.

Note you do not have to assign the result to anything. s/// modifies the argument string.

Comment: Yes, that is a very good point. I may have cases where another underscore may exist. Thank you.

Comment: Your example to replace the first occurrence of an underscore worked great. I've tried to use the same to remove up the last occurrence of "/" in a path string such as /home/usr/name using the following and does not work $path =~ s/^.+\///; Any suggestion as to why this does not work? My desired outcome is for $path = name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
$string = "AA_name";
($name,undef) = $string =~ /(.*)_.*/;
print "name=$name", ",Val=" , $string;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i understand the regex here. However, what if the separator in my string was a dot. Such as AA.name?

Comment: Then you should have a regex like $string =~ /(.*)\..*/

Comment: This will give `AA`  in $name, not `name`  as wanted. Also, why are you using `($name,undef)` instead of `($name)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "AA_name";
( my $n = $string ) =~ s/.*_//;
print $n;
```

Output:

```
name
```

If the separator is a dot, you can use `s/.*\.//` (escaping the dot) or you can use a character class: `s/.*[.]//`.

Comment: Escape the dot or character class. Thank you for making me a bit more wiser with regex.

Comment: @user2674514 - Escape the dot, as it's a meta-character that  matches any single character except newline (unless a certain flag is set).